# Converting roman numerals to integers in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, integer

I have a large list if lists (this is just some of the top rows):

```
['001-008  I', 'I', 'Enfermedades infecciosas y parasitarias', 2018, 6.398]
['001-008  I', 'I', 'Enfermedades infecciosas y parasitarias', 2017, 6.819]
```

And want to apply a function that I have to convert the second column to integers and add it behind the second column, so that the output would look as follows (don't mind the last two columns):

```
['001-008 I', 'I', 1, 'Enfermedades infecciosas y parasitarias', 1984, 3232]
['001-008 I', 'I', 1, 'Enfermedades infecciosas y parasitarias', 1992, 16]
```

The function I wrote before is:

```
def roman_to_int(r):
    rom_vals = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000} 
    result = 0 
    for i,c in enumerate(r):
        if (i+1) == len(r) or rom_vals[c] >= rom_vals[r[i+1]]: 
            result += rom_vals[c]
        else:
            result -= rom_vals[c]
    return(result)
```

I've tried a list comprehension and concatenation, but it seems you can't concatenate a function. I was able to return the list of only the converted values (integers), but wasn't able to add it to the initial list.

Comment: You actually seem to be inserting an int vs converting in your example. Which is it?

Comment: So you are saying that your function works fine, you just don't know how to use it to return the list with the integer added? If so, why not share your attempt at that bit?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. 
The function works fine for converting and will return the corresponding int of a roman numeral. 
My problem lies at returning the initial list with the int column added. 

I've tried: 
for row in lst:
    map(roman_to_int(row), list)
Also: 
lst = [[row[:2] + roman_to_int(row[1]) + row[3:] for row in matches]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use insert():

```py
lst = [['001-008  I', 'I', 'Enfermedades infecciosas y parasitarias', 2018, 6.398],
       ['001-008  I', 'I', 'Enfermedades infecciosas y parasitarias', 2017, 6.819],
       ...]

for row in lst:
    row.insert(2, roman_to_int(row[1])) # changed here
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I've tried it, but it gives me a keyword error...

Comment: I've converted the list of lists to a dataframe and am trying to to do it with apply, but it gives me same error. 
The functino is the one defined above and then I tried your for loop. 
Maybe it's because the function takes only a string. 
I've also tried the following: 
`
    for row in matches: 
        for elem in row[1:2]:
            row.insert(2, roman_to_int(elem))`
It gives me the same key error:
KeyError: '-'

Comment: The full error goes as follows:
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-784bde49923f> in <module>
     54 for row in matches:
     55     for elem in row[1:2]:
---> 56         row.insert(2, romano_a_entero(elem))
     57 
     58 

<ipython-input-13-784bde49923f> in romano_a_entero(r)
     37     resultado = 0
     38     for i,c in enumerate(r):
---> 39         if (i+1) == len(r) or diccionario[c] >= diccionario[r[i+1]]:
     40             resultado += diccionario[c]
     41         else:

KeyError: '-'

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in my answer, take a look at my edited anser - I changed ```roman_to_int(lst[1])``` to ```roman_to_int(row[1])``` That should(?) fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks again! Really appreciate it. 
The key error was due to some errors that occurred previously, because of some unclean data.  Finally I was able to solve it.